# Allowing SVGs while using Helmet middleware

Tags: express, svg, ionicons, helmet.js

My current Helmet configuration is preventing SVGs from loading on my express app. My app attempts to load SVG files from Ionicons which requires the use of the following script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

In my app.js file, I have the following ContentSecurityPolicy configuration:

```
app.use(
 helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    directives: {
      ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
      "img-src": ["'self'", `${process.env.AWS_OBJECT_URL}`],
      "script-src": ["'self'","https://unpkg.com/"],
    },
  },
}));
```

Regular images load fine but SVGs do not load. Under the Helmet directives, I have attempted to allow the necessary script from the Ionicon domain (i.e. https://unpkg.com) but I get the following error message:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Helmet.js maintainer here. I don't exactly know what's going wrong here, but it seems like something (maybe Ionicons) is trying to load an inline script (e.g., `<script>...</script>`) which is disallowed by your CSP. I think it's worth trying to track down what's causing that.

Comment: Thanks @EvanHahn for taking a look.  I see that beginning with v4.0.0 helmet made several changes related to CSP.   For now, I've set `contentSecurityPolicy: false` in my configuration per https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide until I'm able to figure this one out.